# Data integration problem - How to integrate similar entities

Tags: java, python, stemming, edit-distance, data-integration

I have a database which has very similar rows within the same table. Those rows are similar because they have nearly equal column values. I need to integrate those corresponding rows into one single row.

For example, those two users (u1 and u2) should be integrated:

```
 u1 = User(name = "William Henry Gates III",
           age = 55,
           nationality = "american",
           alma_mater = "Harvard Univesity")

 u2 = User(name: "William Henry 'Bill' Gates III",
           age: 55,
           nationality: "America",
           alma_mater: "Harvard U.")
```

I am thinking of using some [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) and [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) techniques. Other algorithms and techniques suggestions? Any helpful libraries to use (preferably in Python or Java)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considered something like [Refine](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/?redir=1)?

Comment: +1 - those folks have done some very sexy things re cleaning up data.

Comment: Great tool, thanks! Complementing your answer, here are the algorithms and techniques that Google Refine use: http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/wiki/ClusteringInDepth